# Yii2 cross origin error on file upload api and other request working fine

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've created yii2 api. I've cross origin origin error on file upload all other request working fine like get, post, put, delete,
issue
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried these type of cross code on my server side.

```
public static function allowedDomains()
{
    return [
        //'*', // star allows all domains
        'http://localhost:5173',
    ];
}

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
        'cors'  => [
            // restrict access to domains:
            'Origin'                           => self::allowedDomains(),
            'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => self::allowedDomains(),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'accept', 'Authorization'],
        ],
]
```

I've tried this method too on server with this method all request working only file upload not working.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
    ]
```

Comment: There is not enough info in your question to tell for sure, but one of the reason why preflight request doesn't pass might be missing route for `OPTIONS` request. Let's say you make route for uploading files something like `POST controller/upload-action`. But when you try to upload your files with ajax the browser first send "preflight" request like this `OPTIONS controller/upload-action`. Because this route doesn't exist the request doesn't reach controller where you've defined the CORS filter behavior. Instead a 404 response with no CORS headers is returned.